# Error al invocar un Servicio SOAP en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap

Estuve tratando de invocar un método de un servicio SOAP en una página en ASP.NET, pero está arrojando el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algunos compañeros de trabajo me indicaron que tocaba invocar el servicio usando WsSecurity y adjuntando una certificaciones previamente enviadas por el proveedor del servicio SOAP; pero no se cómo poder realiza esta operación. Existe alguna guía de cómo de realizar esto?

Gracias

Comment: podrías poner el código del web.config o la llamada al servicio?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar ese proceso si usas las extensiones WSE. Te dejo un enlace [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529565.aspx) de la MSDN (en ingles) donde puedes realizar la firma y el cifrado de la peticion SOAP antes de enviarlo al servicio